# Start collecting user data after app has already been live for a while

Tags: facebook, user-data

I have a basic question about a facebook app I am building. In the first phase, we are building the app so that it doesn't collect any user information, thus keeping the user from having to click the "allow" button to use the app. However, we are considering adding features to the app later on that would require user information. I am just curious if it is a good idea to build it like this, or if we should just collect user information from the start. Would users think it is strange for an app to start collecting data after the app is already live? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: see also this thread: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7479949/how-can-i-reduce-the-information-my-application-requests/7485575#7485575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not a bad idea. Actually Facebook [recommends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Extended_Permissions/) only asking for a permission when needed:

> As a best practice, you should only request extended permissions at
>   reasonable times when the user engages with features that would
>   require their use. For example, if you are asking the user for the
>   publish_stream permission in order to create a custom share UI, the
>   user will better understand the context behind your request if
>   presented with the permission while interacting with the app's share
>   functionality.

*Please DO visit the document I linked to.*

Comment: This is correct, however he is asking about basic permissions though, like to collect only uid, etc. Facebook's recommendations are for extended permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That answers my question. I didn't realize that you could require user information for only specific parts of an app.